# Displaying %variables% is blank/missing when running a batch file in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, invisible

OK, inside of my BAT (batch) file I am trying to detect the number of physical cores of the Windows machine, then display that to the user. I am using 'wmic' which I have confirmed is working properly in a command prompt in retuning the correct information. However, when I try to display the value I have stored, it just shows a blank space.

For example, when I run this, the last line just shows "You have physical cores", and there is just a space between the word "have" and "physical", even though that's where the value of %cpuvar2% is supposed to be showing. I cannot figure out why this is not showing. I have tried with @ECHO ON as well, but no luck.

```
:labelCPU
@ECHO OFF

REM Intro message to let the user know what is happening
ECHO Detecting CPU cores...

REM Command to get the number of physical cores and store as a string var
wmic computersystem get numberoflogicalprocessors> cpuvar

REM Command to remove the first line of junk text from the returned string and save as a new var
MORE +1 cpuvar> cpuvar2

REM Output the number of physical cores to the user
ECHO You have %cpuvar2% physical cores!
```

System: Windows 10 Pro, x64

Comment: Use `set` to set variables. `>` is for sending output to text files.

Comment: Where on the Internet did you see an example of storing the output of a command into a variable using redirection? You are using redirection to a file in your first WMIC command and then using the MORE command to display that file.  Did you somehow think that the functionality changed with the last redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example for you to study.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Echo Detecting CPU cores...
Set "NumCores=0"
For /F EOL^=N %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 ComputerSystem Get NumberOfLogicalProcessors 2^>NUL'
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%H In ("%%G") Do Set "NumCores=%%H"
Echo You have %NumCores% physical cores!

Pause
```